# In Jquery how to add Css?

Tags: jquery, css

In Jquery on Clicking div I need to display result in popup style.I have written Css inside Jquery itself.Please give any suggestions.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style>
#newdiv {
cursor:pointer;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#newdiv").click(function() {
    $("#result").html("Hello World").css("position","fixed","width","380px","height","200px","top","50%","left","50%","margin-left","-190px","margin-top","-100px","background-color","#ffffff","border","2px solid #336699","padding","0px","z-index","102","font-family","Verdana","font-size","10px");
  });
  });
 </script>

 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="newdiv">
 Click
 </div>
 <div id="result"></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: What did you see when you [looked at the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When adding multiple CSS properties you need to pass them in an object:

```
$("#result").html("Hello World").css({
    "position": "fixed",
    "width": "380px",
    "height":"200px",
    "top": "50%",
    "left": "50%",
    "margin-left": "-190px",
    "margin-top": "-100px",
    "background-color": "#ffffff",
    "border": "2px solid #336699",
    "padding": "0px",
    "z-index": "102",
    "font-family": "Verdana",    
    "font-size": "10px"
});
```

I would also strongly suggest that you should not set that many CSS attributes using JavaScript. Instead, create a CSS class and apply that to the element instead:

```css
.foo {
    position: fixed,
    width: 380px,
    height: 200px,
    top: 50%,
    left: 50%,
    margin-left: -190px,
    margin-top: -100px,
    background-color: #ffffff,
    border: 2px solid #336699,
    padding: 0px,
    z-index: 102,
    font-family: Verdana,    
    font-size: 10px
}
```

```js
$("#result").html("Hello World").addClass('foo');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#newdiv").click(function() {
            $("#result").html("Hello World").css({'position':'fixed',
                'height':200,
                'width':300
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```